# Haskell compare two int with if statement

Tags: if-statement, haskell

I want to implement a function named log2, which computes the integer log (base 2) of its argument. I can't use log function. My solution is: to check if x equals to 2^y. If x equals 2^y give the value y, if x doesn't equals to 2^y then y = y + 1. This will go on until y is found. This is what I got so far:

```
log2 x = y where y = 0
    if x == 2^y then y
    else y = y + 1
```

When I want to run this I will get this error:

> error: parse error on input `if'

I am new to Haskell so can somebody explain me what's wrong?

Comment: Haskell uses indentation and spacing to indicate scope of expressions. Your `if` statement is indented in such a way that indicates that it is outside of the `where` clause.

Comment: Do I need to put the if and else statement underneath the where statement, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to explain precisely why the syntax error arises, given that it is not obvious to what (valid) syntax it is intended to correspond. Suffice to say you have essentially written `log2 x = 0` `if .....`. One might expect the second phrase to be a definition or part of the same expression as the `0`, but `if` begins neither.

More generally, Haskell does not have mutable variables. You cannot "assign" to `y`. The closest to what you want would be something like,

`log2 x = until (\y -> x == 2^y) (\y -> y + 1) 0`

Notice that we are never assigning to `y`, we simply bind it to execute each lambda expression. We can imagine it receiving a different name each time! and that would be fine.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation, if I run this and use 10 for x it won't work. But if I use 4 for x it will. How is this possible and how can we fix this?

Comment: Well, your original program only works for exact powers of `2` right? One way to improve it would be to write `>=` instead of `==`, then at least it will halt for `10`. But you'll need something more complicated than adding `1` each iteration to find exact logarithms.